# WCF doesn't serialize all properties

Tags: .net, wcf, serialization, soap, service

I'm consuming a SOAP service that has been imported as a Service Reference in VS2010. I call one of the services with a request object that is provided by the service. The problem I'm having is that not all properties of the object are serialized, or rather not sent over the wire. The request object looks like this:

```
var serviceRequest = new UpdateRequest{
    StoreId = request.StoreId,
    Id = request.Id,
    Status = (Status)Enum.Parse(typeof(Status), request.myStatus.ToString()),
    parameters = request.Parameters,
    validFrom = request.ValidFrom.Value,
    validFromSpecified = request.ValidFromSpecified
};
```

And here is what is sent over the wire. I've captured it with wireshark

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<updateStore xmlns="http://localhost.service.com/">
    <StoreRequest>
    <StoreId>1234</StoreId>
    <validFrom>2011-11-29T00:00:00</validFrom>
    <parameters>
        <param1>true</param1>
    </parameters>
    </StoreRequest>
</updateStore>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Two of the parameters, Id and Status have not been sent to the service, and I just can't figure out why. The values are being set and the WSDL generated properties are public and have the same serialization attributes as the properties that are being serialized.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit----
Updated with service reference generated code

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.233")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://myservice.com/")]
public partial class StoreUpdateRequest : object,        
System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private long StoreIdField;        
    private long IdField;        
    private bool IdFieldSpecified;        
    private Status StatusField;        
    private bool StatusFieldSpecified;        
    private long storeIdField;        
    private bool storeIdFieldSpecified;        
    private System.DateTime validFromField;        
    private bool validFromFieldSpecified;        
    private System.DateTime validToField;        
    private bool validToFieldSpecified;        
    private technicalParameters parametersField;        
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
    public long StoreId {
        get {
            return this.StoreIdField;
        }
        set {
            this.StoreIdField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("StoreId");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)]
    public long Id {
        get {
            return this.IdField;
        }
        set {
            this.IdField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Id");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe an obvious question, what Types ar Id and Status? Are their Types public?

Comment: Can you post the definition of your UpdateRequest?

Comment: Id and Status also have to be properties (with get() and set()) and not only fields...

Comment: are they `public` ? do they have both `get` and `set` ? are they marked `[Obsolete]`? or `[XmlIgnore]` ? Is there a `ShouldSerializeId()` method? or an `IdSpecified` property? lots of unknowns here, where seeing the type would help. If this is a `[DataContract]`, do they have `[DataMember(...)]` etc

Comment: Do you have any more properties (like the `ValidFromSpecified`) in your `UpdateRequest` that are also accompanied by a `bool` property of the same name + `Specified` ?? In that case - you **must** set the `(property)Specified` value to true - otherwise, that property **won't be serialized** - whether it has a value assigned to it or not.

Comment: They are all public with getters and setters, here is some of the generated definition
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.233")] [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://myservice.com/")]

Comment: and the rest
 public partial class StoreUpdateRequest : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {
private long IdField;
private bool IdFieldSpecified;
private Status StatusField;    
private bool StatusFieldSpecified;
 /// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
 public long StoreId {get { return this.StoreIdField;}
    set {this.StoreIdField = value;
    this.RaisePropertyChanged("StoreId");}}
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)]
public long Id {get {return this.IdField;}set {this.IdField = value;
this.RaisePropertyChanged("Id");}}

Comment: Ah, sh*t, they have updated the service reference, those where not optional before, you are so right, I was missing the Specified values for those two properties. Some times you just get blinded when staring at a problem

Comment: Gargamel, if that resolved your problem, please leave an answer stating that so everyone else knows your problem is resolved.

Comment: @marc_s - sorry to revive this old thread after 8+ years. Is there an MSDN link that talks about `xxSpecified` ? It worked by the way.

Answer (score 26):

The problem is resolved. The error was that the SOAP service had been updated and some properties now where optional.
When a field/property say **XX** is marked as optional in a SOAP message WCF creates an corresponding extra **XXIsSpecified** property that must be set to **true** when the **XX** value is set. Otherwise WCF will not serialize nor send that property.

There are different ways to see if a property is set as optional.

- In the generated Reference.cs file each optional will have a corresponding IsSpecified property, like so: `private System.DateTime validFromField;
  private bool validFromFieldSpecified;`
- You can use [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) to see and test the wsdl
- Browse to the wsdl with chrome or another browser and see if the element has the minoccurs attribute. If it's there and it has the value of 0 then it's optional. like this `<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="validFrom" type="xs:dateTime"/>`