# WCF Service loses date on call from client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, wcf

I have a WCF service that serves an MVC application.  From the client, I've downloaded a complex object that has a date property. All good so far.  I display the object's data in a view make edits to other properties and post the view.  On post, the model calls a method on the service to send the object up for processing in the service.  Here's where the problem starts.  The date/time field that came down fine is null when received in the service method.  All other data elements are fine.  I inspected the property value in the model method and it was correct up to that point.  I'm sending back the same value I originally got from the service in this case.

FYI, the service is written in VB, the MVC app is in C#.  I can't figure out what the problem is.  I've checked everything I can think of and all looks good.  All suggestions will be welcomed!

Edited to add code as requested:

Note: The value was originally acquired by the client via the service as an object of type Tran_Issue from

Value inspected in C# method SaveIssueTran():

```
?issue.IssuedOnDateTime
```

{11/25/2013 2:20:26 PM}
    Date: {11/25/2013 12:00:00 AM}
    Day: 25
    DayOfWeek: Monday
    DayOfYear: 329
    Hour: 14
    Kind: Unspecified
    Millisecond: 0
    Minute: 20
    Month: 11
    Second: 26
    Ticks: 635209860260000000
    TimeOfDay: {14:20:26}
    Year: 2013

Value as inspected on the first line of code in the service method (VB.Net):

```
?issue.IssuedOnDateTime
```

## 12:00:00 AM

Service Method Code:

```
    Function SaveIssueTran(ByVal Issue As Tran_Issue, _
                       ByVal CurrentUserEmployeeID As String) As Tran_Issue _
                   Implements IROAMHostSvc.SaveIssueTran

    Dim messages As New Notification
    Try
        'validate the incoming xml tran data
        If Not Issue.Validate(messages) Then
            messages.RegisterMessage("Transaction details:", Issue.ToString)
            ROAMHostClassLib.LogMessages("Detail transaction validation errors for : " &     Issue.TransactionID, messages, True, True)
            Return Issue
        End If

        Return SaveDetailTransaction(Issue, CurrentUserEmployeeID)

    Catch ex As Exception
        messages.RegisterMessage("ROAMHostSvc.vb.SaveIssueTran()", ex.ToString)
        messages.RegisterMessage("Transaction details: ", Issue.ToString)
        ROAMHostClassLib.LogMessages("Error saving detail transaction object for         TransactionID " & Issue.TransactionID & _
                                     ", TransactionID " & Issue.TransactionID, messages, True, True)
        Issue.Messages = messages
        Return Issue
    End Try
End Function
```

Client method that calls the service method:

```
        public static ROAMHostSvc.Tran_Issue SaveIssueTran(ROAMHostSvc.Tran_Issue issue, 
                                                        string currentUserEmployeeID)
    {
        ROAMHostSvc.ROAMHostSvcClient hostSvc = null;
        try
        {
            hostSvc = new ROAMHostSvc.ROAMHostSvcClient();
            issue = hostSvc.SaveIssueTran(issue, currentUserEmployeeID);
            return issue;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            CommonMethods.Close_WCF_Service(ref hostSvc);
        }
    }
```

Class Property (the one that's OK on client, null in service method):

```
    <DataMember()> _
Public Property IssuedOnDateTime As Date
    Get
        Return _issueDateTime
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Date)
        _issueDateTime = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Object declaration:

```
<DataContract()> _
Public Class Tran_Issue
    Inherits TransactionDetailBase
```

Service Method the object was originally acquired from:

```
Function GetIssueTran(ByVal BatchID As String, _
                        ByVal TransactionID As String) As Tran_Issue _
                    Implements IROAMHostSvc.GetIssueTran

    Dim issueTran As Tran_Issue
    issueTran = GetTranDetailObject(BatchID, TransactionID, TransactionTypes.Issue)
    Return issueTran
End Function
```

Comment: In which format you're passing dates?

Comment: As property of object.  the object was defined in a class library in VB.Net.  This particular app is consuming the service from C#/MVC.  There are several other apps that are also consuming the service from VB and C# both.  When I inspected the date value it was displayed in curly braces as {11/25/2015 10:15 AM} in the MVC method that calls the service.  The service accepts that object type as one of it's parameters.  I also checked the class declaration and the property and class are properly decorated.

Comment: Edited my original post to add code as requested.  Also added inspection values.

Comment: The default formatter that WCF uses for RPC-style messages requires the complex types to be annotated with System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract. Can you check if Trans_Issue is properly annotated with DataContract and DataMember?

Comment: See the code I posted.  Both the class and property are so decorated.  What's giving me fits about this is that the property value I'm sending back is the same one I originally got from the same service.  Other values might be edited in the View, but not that one.

Comment: I found a work-around at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311871/wcf-doesnt-serialize-all-properties, however, it begs the question of what the best practice should be?  In looking at the WSDL as the article suggests, I see that ALL of my properties have minOccurs=0 and are thus optional. I looked some more but don't see how to make them required.  Does anyone know what the best practice is?  Seems silly to have to add code to say yes, my property has a value therefore you should send it.  ...pulls hair in frustration :)  I ran a quick test and by setting the ...Specified=true it went up.

Comment: OK... found what I think the best practice is; comments are most welcome in case I'm wrong.  Just adding the DataMember() attribute to the property isn't enough, although that's what all the examples show.  If one adds DataMember(IsRequired:=True) then the wsdl shows no minoccurs attribute, but rather, nillable=true and serialization works fine.  Not only that, but the generated property [PropName]Specified is not generated anymore.  Good article at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff183866.aspx